# LyX as template for automated document generator

Tags: lyx

I used ERT (raw TeX code) in LyX to create PHP template for my documents. When document is exported to LaTeX, this PHP statements are intact and after processing by PHP I get real LaTeX document.

So the entire process is this:

```
LyX  ---export--->  PHP  ---execution--->  LaTeX  ---lualatex--->  PDF.
```

But including RAW PHP code into template is a bit inpractical while writing the template, since preview feature is broken (PHP is not compatible with LaTeX, obviously). And writing  tags is very annoying. But it is working.

So, how to do this better?

[image: example]

(The `tex()` function escapes string for use in LaTeX and prints it.)

Thank you.

Comment: maybe use some template language instead? for example mustache: http://mustache.github.io/ there are libraries for parsing for both php and lua. what kind of stuff are you doing with php? maybe you can use luatex directly, without immediate steps

Comment: There is a lot of PHP code behind to load data from database - it is an export component of a large application. Point in using LyX is to create template easily, without need to wite LaTeX code directly.

Comment: Mustache looks like a step in the right direction. But it is not valid LaTeX code, so {{#this}} throws an error in preview. Is there a way how to let LaTeX accept these constructs?

Comment: maybe escape hashes, like {{\#this}}? or use some other character like {{-this}}. in both cases, you can use str_replace in your php code to convert it back to {{#this}}

Comment: I really do not want to modify once generated code. It would introduce too many potential problems and processing would became more complex than neccessary.

Comment: Seems like you want to do something similar to knitr? Note that there is support for knitr in LyX.

Comment: If I understand Knitr correctly, it does something similar to what I want, but I do not see how I could use it :(

Comment: @JosefKufner take a look at the knitr documentation. For example, http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/ (php is not listed there but you can add it). See if that's what you want.

Comment: Also consider "External Templates" (see Help > Customization)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one very simple idea that is only a slight variation of what you're currently doing. Put the following into the local layout of your LyX file (in document settings):

```
InsetLayout Flex:PHP
  LyxType     Custom
  Decoration  Classic
  KeepEmpty   1
  LabelString PHP
  LatexType   Paragraph
  PassThru    1
End
```

Now to insert PHP, instead of using a TeX inset use Insert -> Custom Insets -> PHP. This act precisely as it currently does: it will export the LaTeX with PHP in place, but will not preview. But while you're working on the document, instead use the following in a local layout:

```
InsetLayout Flex:PHP
  LyxType     Custom
  Decoration  Classic
  KeepEmpty   1
  LabelString PHP
  LatexType   Environment
  LatexName   verbatim
  PassThru    1
  Preamble
    \RequirePackage{verbatim}
  EndPreamble
End
```

This will make all the PHP commands come out literally in the PDF. I'm afraid I can't think of a much better way of switching between the two options. One slight improvement is to include both commands, but rename the one not in use to something else (like PHP1). A better idea is to put the two commands in modules, and switch which module the document uses depending on what stage you're at.

Answer (score 1):

After some time I create a libray which combines Twig with LyX to create beautiful PDF documents from PHP with as little effort as possible.

See https://github.com/jkufner/lyx-on-twig.

The trick is that Twig can be configured to use custom syntax for commands and values, so it can interpret LaTeX macros. So when Twig is not used, LaTeX creates PDF preview of the template with symbols instead of data. When Twig is used, it replaces the macros before LaTeX is invoked, so the output contains the data. One way or another, PDF is generated. It is a bit dirty, but it works quite well.

Btw, make sure you use LuaLaTex, since it can deal with UTF-8.